# Broadcast variable null in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I'm trying to pass a constant value from driver to spark workers.
I've tried following 2 ways but both of them seems to have null values in the workers:

1.

```
    public static Dataset<SomeType> foo(Dataset<RSMRecommendation> dataset) {
        String x = "test"; // I'm reading this value from somewhere else
        
        Dataset<SomeType> ans =  dataset.map((MapFunction<SomeType, SomeType>) row -> {
          ...  
          // here x is null
        }, Encoders.bean(SomeType.class)).persist();
    }
```

2. Using broadcast variables

```
    public static Dataset<SomeType> foo(Dataset<RSMRecommendation> dataset, Broadcast<String> x) {
        
        // x.value is not null here

        Dataset<SomeType> ans =  dataset.map((MapFunction<SomeType, SomeType>) row -> {
            // here x.value() is null
        }, Encoders.bean(SomeType.class)).persist();
    }
```

The class which calls foo method is creating this broadcast variable as:

```
        Broadcast<String> broadcastVar = sparkContext.broadcast("test");
```

I've spent a lot of time on this, any help will be appreciated!
Thank you!